# How to map an internal array from a json inside an html() method?

Tags: javascript

Consider this sample json

```
[ 
  { 
    "img": "remix.jpg",
    "name": "The Remix",
    "desc": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.",
    "ingredients": [
      "Carrots",
      "Celery",
      "Apple",
      "Ginger"
    ]
  }
]
```

and this is my structure

```
$("#juices").html(`
  ${data.map(item => `
    <div>
      <div class="uk-card uk-card-default">
        <div class="uk-card-media-top">
          <img src="./assets/images/specialty-drinks.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt="Specialty Drinks">
        </div>
        <div class="uk-card-body">
          <h3 class="uk-card-title heading">${item.name}</h3>
          <p>${item.desc}</p>
          <ul class="uk-list uk-list-divider">
            <li>${item.ingredients}</li>                    
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `).join('')}                      
`)
```

This generates a stringed list of the ingredients array as you can see in the image. I want to use the map array function so I can display them individually in each `<li>`

This didn't work

```
<ul class="uk-list uk-list-divider">
    ${item.ingredients}.map(ingredient => `
        ${ingredient}
    `)                  
</ul>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't return right away, but open the function, `map()` your ingredients and then return the DOM:

```
$("#juices").html(`
    ${data.map(item =>  {
        const ingredients = item.ingredients.map(i => `<li>${i}</li>`).join('')

        return (`
            <div>
                <div class="uk-card uk-card-default">
                    <div class="uk-card-media-top">
                      <img src="./assets/images/specialty-drinks.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt="Specialty Drinks">
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-card-body">
                      <h3 class="uk-card-title heading">${item.name}</h3>
                      <p>${item.desc}</p>
                      <ul class="uk-list uk-list-divider">
                          ${ingredients}        
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        `)
    }.join('')}                      
`)
```